# Description of $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ as an extension of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$

Tags: number-theory

The ring $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ has $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as an ideal, with a quotient ring again isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. Is there a way to describe the structure of $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ based on this observation?

I tried writing elements of $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ as $kp+i$ with $0\leq k, i\leq p-1$. This representation is unique, and it's not difficult to get expressions for the representation of a sum and product of two elements expressed with that representation. But the problem is that we don't have $kp+i\equiv k'+pi'\mod p^2$ if and only if $k\equiv k'\mod p$ and $i\equiv i'\mod p$, so I can't see how to actually use this to describe the structure  of $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Although ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, there is no ring extension from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ as your title seems to suggest.

Comment: @hardmath Oh, right. That's what I meant.

Comment: The term [lifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) is often used in connection with taking a "solution" in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and constructing a solution in  $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ (or higher powers) that maps down onto the original solution via the canonical homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The ring $A=\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ has an ideal $I=(p)$ which is nilpotent and, in fact, has square zero. The quotient $A/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and we therefore have what is sometimes called an infinitessimal extension of rings $$0\to I\to A\to A/I\to 0$$ There is a whole theory dealing with such extensions, and they are classified using MacLane cohomology (the original reference is [S. MacLane. Homologie des anneaux et des modules. Coll. Topologie Algébrique (1956), pp. 55–80 Louvain]

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for writing $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to mean $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ below.

The funny thing about the cyclic rings, namely $\mathbb{Z}$ and the rings $\mathbb{Z}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, is that their multiplicative structure is completely determined by their additive structure (together with the data of which element is $1$). In fact each of these rings is canonically isomorphic to the endomorphism ring of its underlying abelian group. More generally, if $R$ is a commutative ring and $R/I$ a quotient of it, then $R/I$ as an $R$-algebra is canonically isomorphic to the endomorphism $R$-algebra of $R/I$ as an $R$-module.

So everything you need to know about $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ as a ring is contained in the data of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ as an abelian group, and so you can use the language of [group extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension) and cohomology. In fact abelian extensions of abelian groups are completely described by the [Ext functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor), and the fact that the extension

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$$

does not split reflects the fact that the group $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_p)$ is nonzero (in fact it's $\mathbb{Z}_p$ again).

Comment: From anyone else, it wouldnot matter much but from you to write $\mathbb Z_n$ it is almost inadmissible! :D

Comment: @Mariano: I just really don't like writing $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$. It makes writing out e.g. the stable homotopy groups of spheres so painful... I haven't decided what notation I should be using for the $p$-adic integers to not conflict but I'm leaning slightly towards $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}_p$.

Comment: You could take advantage f the fact that they are the Witt vectors on $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and write them $W(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the ring $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ is the same as the structure of the group $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ and both can be extracted from the canonical projection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ which has kernel $p^2\mathbb Z$.

As a group, $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ is cyclic and cannot be written as the product of two smaller groups.

Comment: Yes, the group is cyclic, and the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ can be mapped 1-1 into $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm sure you don't mean to suggest the same can be done with the respective rings.

Comment: I meant the lattice of ideals is the same as the lattice of subgroups.